# Stop Enter press from lock screen to be recieved by focused application on desktop

Tags: keyboard, lock-screen

When my screen is locked (e.g. due to inactivity or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and I unlock it by entering my password and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that last keystroke is also received by the focused application on the now unlocked desktop.

For example, if I have my browser open and am currently editing a comment here on Ask Ubuntu and then quickly lock and unlock the screen as described, the comment gets sent right after unlocking, which is not desired.

Testing the behaviour with `xev` monitoring my keystrokes, it seems like if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> extremely shortly to unlock the screen, it does not get received on the dektop. However, this "extremely shortly" is difficult to achieve and to remember.

Can there somehow be a delay added e.g. to the lock screen so that it stays enabled for another 100ms or so or until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is released? Or is there another way to stop this keyboard event from getting through?

Comment: Sounds like a bug...

Answer (score 0):

#### Create dbus monitor script Ubuntu 16.04

You could create this script which is invoked by dbus after screen is unlocked. Call the script from your ***Startup Applications*** and it will always be running.

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-monitor --session "type=signal,interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session,member=Unlocked" | 
  while read MSG; do
    LOCK_STAT=`echo $MSG | awk '{print $NF}'`
    if [[ "$LOCK_STAT" == "member=Unlocked" ]]; then
        logger "Screen unlocked"
        # Flush keyboard buffer
        while read -e -t 1; do : ; done.
    fi
  done
```

Note this is for Unity under Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier versions have different methods. Different desktop environments may have different methods as well.

This code works for other utilities however the `#Flush keyboard buffer` section is new and untested.